# Create a program that constructs a Rectangle object (java.awt.Rectangle)

Tags: java

I'm using Dr. Java and the language is java ...i'm a beginner 
* just a basic rectangle

Problem:

Create a program that constructs a Rectangle object (java.awt.Rectangle). The object should have a `getWidth(5)` and a `getHeight(8)`
 compute and `System.out.println()` the area of the Rectangle object. Then compute the perimeter and print it as well.

**what i have so far**

```
//finding the area
int Width = 5;
int Height = 8;
Rectangle bob = new Rectangle(0,0,5,8);
double area = bob.getWidth()*bob.getHeight();
System.out.println("area = " + area);

 // Find the perimeter  
double perimeter = 2*(bob.getHeight()) + 2*(bob.getWidth()); 
System.out.println("get the perimeter = " + perimeter);`
```

Comment: This sound like a direct homework question taken from a book.  What have you tried?  Can you narrow down your issue to one question?

Comment: public class Homework1 
import java.awt.Rectangle;  
{

  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    getWidth(5);
    getHeight(8);
  }

  /* ADD YOUR CODE HERE */
  
}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  You are expected to attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then ask a _specific_ question when you run into a problem.  Just posting your homework with no evidence of having even tried is not acceptable.

Comment: i have tried and i am trying but ppl need to see what im trying to get to because explain this problem isnt easy i have given what i did so far but i dont know if it is correct and it wont complie.

Comment: @user1678800 You are posting "code snippets" without the corresponding error messages.  This means we must _guess_ the error and then _guess_ a solution to that _possible error_.  In other words, we will be guessing and the possibly solving the _wrong_ problem.  We don't like to waste our time working on the _wrong problem_, so you won't get many people willing to help unless you can _describe_ the error beyond "it doesn't work", or the dressed up version of it doesn't work, "it won't compile".  Compilers emit warnings and error messages, please include them.

Comment: @Mat I can't believe that SO is deprecating the homework tag.  I'm sure they mean well, but it seems like such a short-sighted strategy.

Comment: @user1678800 If your two snippets of code are in the same window as you have displayed, then you have defined the name `bob` twice.  This won't work in the same "scope of reference" and will raise an error.  The reason it raises such an error is because when you then use the name `bob`, the computer wouldn't be able to know _which_ bob you were referring to, the one initialized with `new Rectangle(10,20,5,8)` or the one initialized with `new Rectangle(5,8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to read up a little on how `System.out.println(...)` works.

```
Rectangle bob = new Rectangle(10,20,5,8); 
double area = bob.getWidth()*bob.getHeight(); 
System.out.println("area = + area");
```

While you do have a variable named `area`, you do not reference it in your `println` statement.  What you have in your `println` statement is one string that happens to have two continuous series of characters that spell "area", but neither one is a reference to the variable name.

```
System.out.println("area = " + area);
```

Is quite different.  There is one string, `"area = "` and a concatenation operator which joins the string to the variable `area` (which will be automatically converted to a `String` type.  It is a fine point of "moving" the terminating quotation mark of the string, but the *meaning* is quite different.

```
"area = + area"
```

one string, with a few funny characters

```
"area = " + area
```

one string, a concatenation operator, and a second name which will be "converted" to a string.

Comment: so will i use this same thing to find the perimeter?

Comment: To determine if rectangles overlap, if you happen to have an `intersection(...)` method, I would expect it to take a `Rectangle` as a parameter and return a `boolean` indicating if the current object intersects with the passed parameter `Rectangle`. If it is part of your homework to write that logic, it should be easy enough if you have had basic Algebra.  Should you have a hard time visualizing the conditions for overlapping rectangles, draw out a couple of rectangles on graph paper.  There is a relationship between the vertices of intersection rectangles.  Test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)? It covers the basics of Java 2D and can help you with your problem.